# Bun:HTMLRewriter infinite loop issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, bun

I was using HTMLRewriter to select each element. This works but the issue is it gets stuck in an infinite loop. Now there is also a twist. If log the index directly:

```js
$(".item").each((index, element) => {
    console.log("index", index);
});
```

It logs:

```bash
index 0
index 1
```

But if I use this and try to log the element content

```js
$(".item").each((index, element) => {
    console.log("index", index);
    console.log($(element).text().trim());
});
```

It gets stuck in an infinite loop and logs the element value multiple time and also the index gets increased. I am pretty sure it's an issue with `.each()` method. Here's the code of the `.each()` function:

```js
    each(callback: (index: number, element: string) => void) {
        let index = 0;

        this.beerio.rewriter
            .on(this.selector, {
                element: (element) => {
                    callback(index++, element.tagName);
                },
            })
            .transform(this.beerio.raw_html);

        return this;
    }
```